# What is this metal material?

Tags: wiring, framing, materials, renovation

[image]

I’m running some networking cable from my attic to my basement (only going through one main level). The best place to run the cabling takes me through an old covered up door (closet) frame on the way down. It was closed off when the house was renovated before we bought it.

I have the holes drilled up from the basement and down from the attic, but about 10-12” down, there is what I assume to be an old header. I have verified that they did not add additional framing in the former doorway with a stud finder. There is no electrical, water, or HVAC  in that wall.

This metal mesh/material is getting in my way. Can anyone add advice?  This is looking with an endoscope straight down from the attic.

Thanks!

Comment: "* but about 10-12” down*"  down from ?  A photo from a distance may help with context.

Comment: looks like a nailhead to me

Comment: Apologies. This is 10-12” down from the top plate in the attic. I’m sure that this is the header of the old closet door frame, but need advice on how to get through it.

Comment: The hole you see there is 1” in diameter. For additional context.

Comment: I was going to agree with nail head until you said it was 1" in diameter.  A photo from a distance may help with context.

Comment: I’ll try to get a distance photo, but it’s hard using the endoscope which doesn’t focus well from a distance.

Comment: Can you check on the other side if there's a nut? 1" is a nice size for a carriage bolt head. Don't understand your context enough to know if it would make sense there.

Comment: Very likely steel, Touch it with a magnet to check. Steel will not be easy to remove.

Comment: I'm impressed that there don't seem to be _any_ marks on it from the drill bit when it hit it and you (I presume) pushed harder trying to get the bit through whatever obstruction you hit before giving up and getting the camera out for a look at what you ran into. That indicates to me that this is a _very_ hard material.

Comment: Does it flex any when you push on it with something like a pencil?  I could see it maybe being the top plate of a steel stud.  In that case I would expect it to drill fairly easily.